# Segmentation fault (core dump) with multiplication of dynamic matrices

Tags: c

I'm writing this code but it's continue on giving me a core dump error but i cannot understand why...This code takes 4 int inputs and two double matrices and gives me two outputs (result and the product matrix). I think the problem is in the allocation but I'm not sure... Thanks in advance for your help!

```
double **calculate product (double** matrix1,
                        double** matrix2,
                        int *result,
                        int dim_rows1,
                        int dim_rows2,
                        int dim_col1,
                        int dim_col2)
{ 
   int i, j, k;
   double** prod_matrix = NULL;

   if(matrix1 == NULL || matrix2 == NULL)
     *result = 0;
   else 
   {
      *result = 1;
      if(dim_col1 == dim_rows2)
      {
         prod_matrix = (double **)malloc((dim_rows1)*sizeof(int *));

         for(i = 0; i < dim_rows1; i++)
         {
            prod_matrix[i] = (double *)malloc((dim_col2)*sizeof(int));
         }

         for(i = 0; i < dim_rows1; i++)
         {
            for(j = 0; j < dim_col2; j++)
            {
               prod_matrix[i][j] = 0;

               for(k = 0; k < dim_rows2; k++)
               {
                  prod_matrix[i][j] += matrix1[i][k]*matrix2[k][j] 
               }
            }
         }
     }
     else
      *result = 0;

  return(prod_matrix);
}
```

An example of main is:

```
int main (void){
    int result,
        dim_col1,
        dim_col2,
        dim_rows1,
        dim_rows2,
        selected;
    double **matrix1 = NULL,
           **matrix2 = NULL,
           **sum_matrix = NULL,
           **prod_matrix = NULL;

    selected = text(); /* client chose a number beetween 1 and 6*/

    switch(selected)
    {
      case 1: /* case 1 and case 2 take the dimension of the matrix */
      .
      . 
      .
      case 5: /* makes sum beetween matrix */
      . 
      .
      case 6: prod_matrix = prod_matrix (matrix1, matrix2, &result, dim_rows1 . . . dim col2)
        if(result == 1)
            //do things
        else
            //do things

    }
return(0);
}
```

I forgot to say, usally it works but when i try with the first one matrix (4,2) and the second one (3,4) it goes always in segmentation fault.

Comment: To answer I think we need to see how `calculate_product` is called. Including how the parameters to the function are allocated. I fear you have passed 2D arrays as first and second parameters.

Comment: C or C++? I don't think it's both.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, please show a `main` including how the function is called.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` could possibly be different than the size of a double.

Comment: About your last edit, you can't multiply a 4x2 matrix by a 3x4, their "inner" dimensions aren't equal. Did you mean a 3x4 multiplied by a 4x2? Are you sure that you are passing the arguments (dimensions) in the correct order?

Comment: @Bob__ You are right you cannot do the product AxB in that case but I have another function that makes the user decide whether to make AxB or BxA and simply pass the parameters to the contrary.

Comment: A minimal verifiable example means complete code. That is, no `...` missing parts in the code. Note that doesn't mean show all the code you have but to construct an example that has all the irrelevant parts removed but still compilable and able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @kaylum i wanted to edit my post with an example but i can't because someone have delete it. I'm new on this platform so i still don't know well how make the perfect post about a problem but i didn't think someone could delete YOUR post. Anyway i gonna try to make onther one with everything the people needs to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Eljay has it.

```
prod_matrix[i] = (double *)malloc((dim_col2)*sizeof(int));
```

should be

```
prod_matrix[i] = (double *)malloc((dim_col2)*sizeof(double));
```

Comment: I tried and it's continuing to go in segmentation fault :(

Comment: @Kev Have you also changed in the prevoius allocation `int *` to `double *`?

Comment: Yes, i did but without succes...